# Creating a 3D talking character iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, 3dsmax

I'm new to iPhone programming, and since winter break is coming up, I thought I might immerse myself in a fun project. I want to create a 3D talking character iPhone app, that interacts with the user based on touch, like the existing talking characters in the AppStore (Talking Santa, Talking Cat, etc). I am familiar with 3DsMax and Maya, but I'm not familiar with the 'gaming' side of iPhone development at all. In general, what is the recipe for creating such an app? If you look at this app,[Talking Santa](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/talking-santa-for-iphone/id398853199?mt=8), would you be able to tell me, in general, the steps they took to create the app? Where did they design it? How did they import it into whatever program that is used to create the app? What else can you tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these types of apps, basically we change images within a particular time in an animation block

Comment: Hi @Swastik, Can u plz provide any example or describe in brief ? THanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to iPhone programming, or especially to programming in general, I suggest you start with a much simpler application.

Having modelling experience is great, but is a completely different skill set from creating an 
app. Creating the model is probably one of the more straight-forward steps required in that.

Try making a simple iPhone app first, say, one that lets a user create a grocery list or something like that, and then move to OpenGL ES, which is the graphics library that was used to render that santa.

If you want a model that complex, you'll need to look into importing models, or other engines/tools that allow you to display and animate models created in Maya or 3DS.

Comment: +1 For simple approach to iPhone dev. It's unbelievable how many questions start with: "I'm new to iPhone programming...".

Comment: Well I'm not that new, but I'd really like to start here. I just want to know the steps involved. If you know, please share. Thanks

Comment: @f-Prime: Learning to make iPhone apps by starting here is like learning to fight by punching Al Capone. ;P

Comment: Man you just dont wanna answer the question do you